# Summing up value in array of objects

Tags: javascript

```
[
{
    "id": {
    "extId": "112",
    "year": "2000"
    },
    "Count": 1
},
{
    "id": {
    "extId": "113",
    "year": "2001"
    },
    "Count": 446
},
{
    "id": {
    "extId": "115",
    "year": "2000"
    },
    "Count": 742
}, ...
]
```

I have a very long array of objects. I need to sum up the count based on the year. For e.g, I would like something like [{2000: 743}, {2001: 446},...].
I am not sure how to proceed with that in javascript. Should I loop through every object in the array and check for the year or is there some javascript function which can make this simpler.

Thanks.

Comment: filter > reduce?

Comment: you can have a look at lodash groupBy function https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#groupBy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array.reduce()`:

```
let countByYear = objects.reduce((acc, next) => {
    acc[next.id.year] = (acc[next.id.year] || 0) + next.Count;
    return acc;
}, {});
```

Note, this will produce a different structure from your example (because I read your question too sloppily):

```
{
    2000: 743,
    2001: 446
}
```

However I would say this is easier to work with than `[ { 2000: 743 }, { 2001: 446 } ]`, since in that case you have an array of objects, that each have a single key, and you have no way of knowing what that key is, which I'd imagine makes it really difficult to iterate over them.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce:

`arr.reduce((result, current) => {
  result.push({[current.year]: current.Count});
  return result
}, [])`

This will give you this structure [{2000: 743}, {2001: 44}] and you can even do `arr.filter(filterFn)` first if you need to filter only certain years

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and take the key/values for an array of objects.

```js
var data = [{ id: { extId: "112", year: "2000" }, Count: 1 }, { id: { extId: "113", year: "2001" }, Count: 446 }, { id: { extId: "115", year: "2000" }, Count: 742 }],
    count = Array.from(
        data.reduce(
            (m, { id: { year }, Count }) => m.set(year, (m.get(year) || 0) + Count),
            new Map
        ),
        ([year, count]) => ({ [year]: count })
    );
    
console.log(count);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
  var arr=[
{
    "id": {
    "extId": "112",
    "year": "2000"
    },
    "Count": 1
},
{
    "id": {
    "extId": "113",
    "year": "2001"
    },
    "Count": 446
},
{
    "id": {
    "extId": "115",
    "year": "2000"
    },
    "Count": 742
}
];
var result=arr.reduce((result, current) => {
  result.push({[current.id.year]: current.Count});
  return result;
}, []);
console.log(result);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

## ES6

You could use **[`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)** function to get required result.

**DEMO**

```js
const data = [{"id": {"extId": "112","year": "2000"},"Count": 1},{"id": {"extId": "113","year": "2001"},"Count": 446},{"id": {"extId": "115","year": "2000"},"Count": 742}];

let result = data.reduce((r, {Count,id: {year}}) => {
  r[year] = (r[year] || 0) + Count;
  return r;
}, {});

console.log([result])
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

`reduce` will do the trick here for you:

```js
var arr = [
{
    "id": {
    "extId": "112",
    "year": "2000"
    },
    "Count": 1
},
{
    "id": {
    "extId": "113",
    "year": "2001"
    },
    "Count": 446
},
{
    "id": {
    "extId": "115",
    "year": "2000"
    },
    "Count": 742
},
{
    "id": {
    "extId": "116",
    "year": "2001"
    },
    "Count": 44
}
];

let count = arr.reduce((acc, next) => {
    acc[next.id.year] = (acc[next.id.year] || 0) + next.Count;
    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var yearCount={};
var temp=[
{
    "id": {
    "extId": "112",
    "year": "2000"
    },
    "Count": 1
},
{
    "id": {
    "extId": "113",
    "year": "2001"
    },
    "Count": 446
},
{
    "id": {
    "extId": "115",
    "year": "2000"
    },
    "Count": 742
}
];
temp.forEach(item=>{
    var val=yearCount[item.id.year];
  if (val){
        yearCount[item.id.year]=val+item.Count;
  }
  else{
    yearCount[item.id.year]=item.Count;
  }
})
console.log(yearCount);
```